# Error compiling code for downloading string and progress bar

Tags: c#

I have some simple code, but it won't compile. I get an error I don't understand.

Trying to compile this code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; } ;
    wc.DownloadString("example.com");
 }
```

And have this error:

> "CS0136  C# A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

What's going wrong?

Comment: What is wrong is that you already have an `EventArgs e` being passed to the click event and you are trying to use the same placeholder for your  progress bar

Answer (score 1):

You can;t use same placeholder `e` for two different "things"
Try changing one of them to `e2` for example